# Jquery has/find/contains not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am checking if a element contains a second element. Previously I have used jquery element.has(secondElement) function.

I am using jquery in angularjs. I have a directive, that I transclude element on to through the markup using ng-transclude.

Mark up :

[image]

Usage:

```
<drop-down
            options="data"
            value="val"
            placeholder="I am split"
            type="split">
        <icon size="medium" name="search-grey"></icon>
    </drop-down>
```

First my source code for the directive:

```
    "use strict";

var DropDownDirectiveDefinition = [
    "Popover",
    function (Popover) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: "js/modules/components/dropDown/dropDown.html",
            scope: {
                data: "=",
                value: "=",
                placeholder: "@"
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
                transclude(scope, function(clone) {
                    scope.transcludedData = clone;
                });
                scope.CheckData = function(event) {
                        if(scope.transcludedData.find(event.target).length > 0) {
                            console.log("Element found!");
                            return;
                        }
                };
            }
        };
    }];

angular
    .module("rpsm")
    .directive("dropDown", DropDownDirectiveDefinition)
;
```

I have a link function in my directive. I am using ng-transclude and I have capture the transcluded element in to scope.transcludedData.

On the directive, I have an ng-click. On click I call checkData and I pass in $event.

I want to check if the event.target is inside the transcluded data.

This is the dump of the transcluded element and the target:

Transcluded element:
[image: Transcluded element]

Target:

[image]

Now I can see the traget is in the translcuded element: 
[image]

However .has(), .find() and .contains() all return false.

This works fine, when I am not checking using a transcluded element.

So my question is, why is jquery find/has/contains function not returning true? Could someone help with this issue? Does transclude break jquery's contains function? By the way, I get no errors.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you share the code for the directive

Comment: @ArunPJohny Updated my question with the full directive source

Comment: @MokkyMiah isn't it should be `angular.element(scope.transcludedData)`

Comment: also this is in the docs : `find() - Limited to lookups by tag name`

Comment: are you using jQuery also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9tmtkv61/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for your help. I have tried angular.element on scope.transcludedData, it had no effect. I am using jquery. Im looking at the jsfiddle now. Also the transcluded data I pass in is another directive called 'icon'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `transclude()` method creates a new dom element, it doesnt return the same element created by `ng-transclude` so the actual element added to the dom and the one referred by `transcludedData` are different that is why it is not working.

So one easy solution is to have a wrapper element for the transcluded elements like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Welcome";
});
app.directive('myTest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      data: "=",
      value: "=",
      placeholder: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.CheckData = function(event) {
        if (element.find('> div > .trans-el').find(event.target).length) {
          snippet.log("Element found!");
          return;
        }
      };
    },
    template: '<div ng-click="CheckData($event)"><div class="trans-el"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>{{value}}<span>x</span></div>'
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <my-test>Some content <span>with span</span></my-test>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add a wrapper element, then another solution is not to use the ng-transclude directive instead to add the transcluded element manually to the dom like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Welcome";
});
app.directive('myTest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      data: "=",
      value: "=",
      placeholder: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone) {
        scope.transcludedData = clone;
        element.children('div').prepend(clone)
      });
      scope.CheckData = function(event) {
        if (scope.transcludedData.is(event.target) || scope.transcludedData.find(event.target).length > 0) {
          snippet.log("Element found!");
          return;
        }
      };
    },
    template: '<div ng-click="CheckData($event)">{{value}}<span>x</span></div>'
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <my-test>Some content <span>with span</span></my-test>
</div>
```

[Transclusion Functions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion-functions)

> If you are just using ngTransclude then you don't need to worry about
>   this function, since ngTransclude will deal with it for us.